# WordPress 3.8 Backend Admin Color Scheme add more scheme how to do?

Tags: theme-development, themes

How can I add additional admin color schemes into Wordpress 3.8?

I want to add two more with a yellow shade and a green shade.

Comment: Please explain your question better. Do not just repeat the title. Share your research efforts, show us what you have tried. Read [ask] again.

Comment: means there are 8 color options are available like Default,light,blue,coffee,Ectoplasm,Midnight,Ocean,Sunrise ect. but i want add two more yellow shade and green shade .

Comment: i hope now understand @toscho .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to learn [Admin Color Schemes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-color-schemes/) plugin which provides 8 new color schemes.

You need to install Grunt.js and SASS compiler. More information you can find during investigation [the plugin stuff](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/admin-color-schemes/trunk). Use it as a copy to create your own plugin.

Comment: Thnks mr @Eugene Manuillov

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
wp_admin_css_color( $key, $name, $url, $colors, $icons );
```

Docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_admin_css_color

It's really straightforward, you add a CSS file and your color options.

Comment: +1 for pointing all of us in the right direction with this. the file is well structured and easy to read and add color combinations too.  My only question is if there is a way from my plugin to concatenate data to register_admin_color_schemes(), so that I don't have to modify core files every time there is a wordpress upgrade.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In WP 3.8, there is a folder called /wp-admin/css/colors

This folder contains the 7 additional (other than default) admin color schemes you can select when editing your user profile.

I'd assume you could copy one of these folders into a new folder, with your own folder name, and then you can edit the CSS contained in the folder.

Upload your new folder to /wp-admin/css/colors and voilà!

Comment: there is not available custom code or can i change there without admin folder .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Yes, you can have a closer look at the plugin [Admin Color Schemes](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-color-schemes/) in the repository and at http://wptavern.com/admin-color-schemer-the-easiest-way-to-customize-wordpress-admin-colors